# How trim a video using FFMPEG in android

Tags: android, android-studio, ffmpeg, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I got

> Fatal signal 11(SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x5 in tid 5823 (e.mypc.videocut)

When I try to debug the app crashes when I'm reading this line:

```
vk.run(complexCommand, workFolder, getApplicationContext());
```

**VideoTrim Screen:**

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)VideoCut.this.getSystemService(Activity.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "VK_LOCK");
Log.d(Prefs.TAG, "Acquire wake lock");
wakeLock.acquire();

LoadJNI vk = new LoadJNI();
try {
    String workFolder=  getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    Log.d("workfolder",workFolder);
    String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg", "-i", path, "-ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1", "/storage/emulated/0/VID.mp4"};

    // String commandStr = "ffmpeg -i "+path +"-ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID.mp4";
    vk.run(complexCommand, workFolder, getApplicationContext());

    Log.i("test", "ffmpeg4android finished successfully");
    GeneralUtils.copyFileToFolder(vkLogPath, demoVideoFolder);

} catch (Throwable e) {
    Log.e("test", "vk run exception.", e);

} finally {
    if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
        wakeLock.release();
        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "Wake lock released");

    } else {
        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "Wake lock is already released, doing nothing");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/rowntreerob/android-ffmpeg/blob/master/Project/src/com/b2bpo/media/notes/RecorderActivity.java#L135 is from old , but was working android/ffmpeg. you can compare the stack there to what u do with segfault. many other working android//ffmpeg projects on git.

Comment: but it not work in android studio

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling, you have ffmpeg build for different ABI. Please provide more information about your environment.